# HtmlUnit javascript event

Tags: htmlunit

I successfull done login with HtmlUnit  on SITE, run a form search and got a page with results.
Now in real world, to get the whole page result I need to scroll the page more times .
But I am using HtmlUnit ,then I have done :

```
List<DIV> res=page.getByXPath(...) // got 13 items
ScriptResult res=page.executeJavaScript("window.scrollBy (0,2000);");
res=page.getByXPath(...) // would get other items,same query as the first
```

The problem is that the query on  page , after the above code is returning the same items as before run JS , the XPath query return same result items .
Instead ,on browser, the scroll work well and return the seconf train of result items.
Then , does HtmlUnit is not designed for this ?  a bug ? or there is another HtmlUnit trick?

I tried also

```
ScriptResult res =page.getBody().fireEvent("scroll");
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As HtmlUnit is a headless browser, the scrolling support is still weak. Please open an issue at gitub about this (including sample code) and i will try to improve the support if possible.

Comment: then there isn't a way to get data loaded only after a scroll ?

Comment: Not sure, I need a reproduce able sample to do more analysis on this.