# Make Ajax request with HtmlUnit

Tags: ajax, htmlunit

I am scraping a site but I am blocked at point to scrolling page result to obtain whole page result .
See [Stackoverflow previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65460163/htmlunit-javascript-event)

What I understand for now is that HtmlUnit can't fire a scroll event , but I am thinking if it is possible to fire the JS code fired by Scroll Event , in this way I can bypass the scroll event and obtaining his result .But , does HtmlUnit can make an Ajax request ?

Comment: Let me repeat: Please open an issue for HtmlUnit and provide some complete minimal reproducable sample code. If i can reproduce the problem you have a good chance to get a fix.

Comment: Yes it can make ajax requests.

Comment: Please , there is some example ?

Comment: Let me try it again - please open an issue for HtmlUnit and let us discuss it. I really like to help you but i need more input from you.